# Make gnuplot's x axis start at 0 instead of the first date

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting some [date, value] formatted data (cpu use over time) and want the xtics to start at 0 or 1 instead of the first date.

So for 10 hours it should look like: `0:01:00, 0:02:00, .., 0:10:00` insead of `9:23:00 ...` (since the first day in the data is the 9th at 11pm).

My current datetime settings:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xtics format "%d:%H:%M" font ",25"
```

**Edit**: If there's a way to just count hours starting from 0 on the x axis without day info that'd be awesome too. Either way. I just want to start counting from 0 to make the "time taken" very clear.

Comment: I played around a bit with various settings, but I couldn't get it to work. The problem arises when you use `%d`, which is 'day of the month', but not the number of days. So the minimum is always `1`, and your output would start with `01:...` at the `0`-position. I have no idea how to bypass this.

Comment: Well, I'd be perfectly happy to even omit the day as long as x axis could have the total hours. I'll edit my answer to add that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work with `set xdata time`, because for the output only the day of the month is available, which is in the range `[1:31]`, so the `0`-position would start with `1`.  The same happens for total number of hours, because that value is limited to `[0:23]`, so that number over `23` are wrapped back.

Here is a solution without time data. I use the `strptime` function to convert the date string to a time stamp (in seconds), which is then divided by 3600 to get the hour (as float number):

The test data file is:

```
2013-08-25 18:45:11 100
2013-08-25 19:11:23 200
2013-08-25 20:00:32 400
2013-08-25 21:00:32 300
2013-08-26 20:11:12 500
```

And the example script:

```
reset
file='data.txt'
fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
start=system('head -1 '.file)
start_stamp = strptime(fmt, start)
plot 'data.txt' using ((strptime(fmt, stringcolumn(1).' '.stringcolumn(2))-start_stamp)/3600.0):3 with lines t ''
```

The first column is extracted with an external tool.

The result is:

[image]

And here is another variant, which uses a more comfortable data format, using commas as separators, and the first column is extracted with gnuplot:

The data file:

```
2013-08-25 18:45:11,100
2013-08-25 19:11:23,200
2013-08-25 20:00:32,400
2013-08-25 21:00:32,300
2013-08-26 20:11:12,500
```

The script file:

```
reset
file='data.txt'
fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set datafile separator ','
plot 'data.txt' using ($0 == 0 ? start_stamp = strptime(fmt, stringcolumn(1)) : 0, \
     (strptime(fmt, stringcolumn(1))-start_stamp)/3600.0):2 with lines t ''
```

The results are equivalent.

**EDIT:** One last variant, which is a mixture @andyras's and my answer. You can use `set timefmt` with an explicit call to `timecolumn` to parse the input as time. The output is then handled like a conventional double number. I use `$0`, i.e. the number of the current sample, to set the offset value:

```
reset
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

offset = 0
t0(x)=(offset=($0==0) ? x : offset, x - offset)

plot 'data.txt' u (t0(timecolumn(1))/3600.0):3 notitle w l
```

Comment: Could you explain what the pseudocolumn $0 is doing in this case?

Comment: @CornSmith See the last script in the edited answer. `$0` is the index of the current row, `$0 == 0` is `true` in the first row.

Comment: Your last variant is brilliant! I had no idea you could even do functions in a gnuplot script.

Comment: Excellent answers--I wanted to do something very much like this (except dividing by 86400.0 to get the absolute number of days), but I could not figure out how to get it into the desired "%d:%H:%M" format with a number of days > 31.

Comment: @andyras When browsing a bit through the documentation I found the `timecolumn` function, but it is almost not documented. And about `set timefmt` the documentation says, that it requires `set xdata time`. Tested a bit to find out how they match together...

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite an answer, but close enough that I am posting it as such.

I have a way that you can start the time file at time zero (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034891/how-do-i-make-a-plot-in-gnuplot-with-the-lowest-value-automatically-subtracted-f) to an old question of mine):

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xtics format "%d:%H:%M" font ",6"

first = 0
offset = 0
# returns data offset by first value
t0(x)=(offset=(first==0)?x:offset,first=1,x-offset)

plot 'data.dat' u (t0(timecolumn(1))):3 notitle
```

Here are some sample data

```
2013-09-16 00:14:00 1
2013-09-26 00:15:00 3
2013-10-04 00:16:00 2
2013-10-19 00:17:00 4
```

and the output:

[image]

This strategy has the problem that once the data go above 31 days the date counter resets.

I could not figure out how to get the xtics format to manipulate data columns.

Comment: This is also a very good answer. I'll use this for data that spans 3+ days, and Cristoph's for the rest. I wish I could mark both as correct. For data >31 days I'll use Cristoph's answer altered for days only instead of hours.